# When Will the Google Webmaster Tools API allow access to the Average Position in the Search Queries section of their tool?

Tags: google-search-console, search-results, api, google-ranking

I'm wondering if anyone has early access to the search queries / average position data via the Google Webmaster Tools API yet?

Do you know of any tools that have access to this part of the API? Does it exist yet? What alternatives to tracking rankings / SERP tracking are there that doesn't involve scraping ranking data from Google?

Answer (score 1):

Ninebyblue has a new product called Blueprint that alludes to Average Position access in GWT, but I don't know of anyone with access so I can't be sure it's not just wishful thinking.

http://www.ninebyblue.com/blueprint/

The Bing Webmaster Tools API also includes Average Position, but that's not as desirable as the Google data.

A temporary measure could be to manually import CSV data from GWT, but long term it needs to be data available from the API.  The Google Analytics team has confirmed that despite GA having access to Average Position, the data still lives in GWT.